# A question about implementing a method in an onClick listener in my Youtube app

Tags: java, android, youtube

im working on a youtube app, and within it i have been able to add time stamps like so.

[image: youtube app]

So the next step for me is to somehow have the youtube video go to the specific point in time where the timestamp was created, by clicking a textView.

This is what i have so far

```java
package com.example.yukiv3.activity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;


import com.example.yukiv3.R;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.views.YouTubePlayerSeekBar;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.views.YouTubePlayerSeekBarListener;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class YTPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public YouTubePlayerView ytPlayer;
    public TextView videoTitle;
    public int time = 0;
    public TextView displayTime;
    public Button button;

    public YouTubePlayerSeekBar youTubePlayerSeekBar;

    LinearLayout lin;

    //    public YTPlayerActivity(YouTubePlayerSeekBar youTubePlayerSeekBar) {
    //        this.youTubePlayerSeekBar = youTubePlayerSeekBar;
    //    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ytplayer);

        ytPlayer = findViewById(R.id.yt_player);
        videoTitle = findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        displayTime = findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
        youTubePlayerSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_seekbar);
        lin = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        lin.removeAllViews();

        Intent data = getIntent();

        final String videoId = data.getStringExtra("video_id");
        String video_title = data.getStringExtra("video_title");
        ytPlayer.addYouTubePlayerListener(youTubePlayerSeekBar);
        ytPlayer.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NotNull final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
                //      doesnt do anything          youTubePlayer.seekTo(time);

                youTubePlayerSeekBar.setYoutubePlayerSeekBarListener(new YouTubePlayerSeekBarListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void seekTo(float time) {
                        youTubePlayer.seekTo(time);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCurrentSecond(@NotNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, float second) {
                super.onCurrentSecond(youTubePlayer, second);
                displayTime.setText(String.valueOf(second));
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final TextView textView = new TextView(YTPlayerActivity.this);

                textView.setText(displayTime.getText());

                final EditText editText = new EditText(YTPlayerActivity.this);

                Button buttonView = new Button(YTPlayerActivity.this);

                buttonView.setText("clear");

                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String s = textView.getText().toString();
                        final Float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
                        editText.setText("Hello world!");

                        ytPlayer.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReady(@NotNull final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                                //                                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId,0);
                                //      doesnt do anything          youTubePlayer.seekTo(time);

                                youTubePlayerSeekBar.setYoutubePlayerSeekBarListener(new YouTubePlayerSeekBarListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void seekTo(float time) {
                                        youTubePlayer.seekTo(f);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCurrentSecond(@NotNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, float second) {
                                super.onCurrentSecond(youTubePlayer, second);
                                displayTime.setText(String.valueOf(second));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                lin.addView(textView);
                lin.addView(editText);
                lin.addView(buttonView);
            }
        });

        //this is where it would be set
        videoTitle.setText(video_title);
    }
}
```

i was trying to use the

youTubePlayer.seekTo(f);

method so that the number value from the text view would be implemented in the above method, but that doesnt seem to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: i was using a youtube tutorial on this app that used java and im used to it. If i switch to Kotlin will this help?

Answer (score 1):

i figured out a solution,

```
youTubePlayerSeekBar.getYoutubePlayerSeekBarListener().seekTo(f);
```

lets me seek to the the desired point in the video